# Default value in a field in the Solr schema can be the current date?

Tags: java, solr

I'm using Solr and I would like to add a field `last_update` in the `schema.xml` where the default value would be the current date when the document is added or updated.

Do you have an idea how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is a [supported scenario](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/working-with-dates.html#now) for [DateField](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/working-with-dates.html). The following should work:

```
<field name="last_update" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" />
```

Comment: Looks like it's not working for pdate in Solr 9.4.0