# Solr supports something like NOW() for /update operation?

Tags: datetime, solr

There is some Solr support to fill a datetime field value with current Solr server time, like NOW() function defined in some general relational databases, i.e. pgsql, mysql, ...?

By example, considering `NOW` some reserved word representing current solr server UTC time. If I send following document to `/update` endpoint:

```
{
"available": false,
"oid": "c5f2788641cb33aea2bb2969a05aede6",
"last_update": NOW
}
```

Expected value on last_update will be current server time.

If there is not something ready, there is some way to extend DateField class or parser to define it?

Considering question [about default value applied on schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317759), I am looking for something dynamic, defined during POST message to /update, not a setup for default value on schema.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default value in a field in the Solr schema can be the current date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317759/default-value-in-a-field-in-the-solr-schema-can-be-the-current-date)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It is really what I was looking for! And, coincidentally, we called the same field, with the same purpose as last_update. Great!

Comment: But, following my question. It is about /update message. Not about default value. There is some way to set NOW value for an input data on /update endpoint.

Comment: According to Solr docs, NOW can be specified as milliseconds since epoch: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates  The example is a select query, but I would expect it to work for updates also. Not exactly what you're looking for, though.